# AC water turbine

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, rectifier, generator, three-phase

I am trying to use a water turbine from China to charge a lithium ion battery. The water turbine is rated to 10 watts.

I figured that should be enough to charge the battery but I can only ever get about 0.1 watts from it.

I took it apart and it looks like it is generating 3 phase AC power and then rectifying it to DC with 6 diodes.

I am then using the LM22672MRE-5.0 switching regulator to regulate the voltage to the MCP73871 battery charge management chip.

Any tips on how to get more power out of it or are the specs just wrong?

[This is the turbine I am using.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07HNXRNMH)

Here is a simplified schematic of the circuit I am using to rectify the 3 phase power and convert it to 5V DC. Should I be doing some kind of impedance matching to make this work better?

[image]

Comment: What is your water source?

Comment: @Mattman944 It's probably not Chinese water. ;) To the OP, it's likely the specs were produced under the best possible case and quite unusual, in practice. Solar panels, for example, are rated for equatorial insolation at noon in crystal clear air. Which, of course, is almost never the situation they are operated under.

Comment: Can you measure the generator Voltage vs current without regulator using an active load? (power NPN) , until Vrms drops 50%.(V/I) (briefly)  then Voc vs flow rate. NOTE the spec is  charging current maximum =220mA.  It says DC 0-80V but what do you get?  That implies source impedance is 80V/0.22A = 360 ohm much higher than your regulator Zin yet with matched load 360 max P=8.9W

Comment: What is the head and flow rate you are supplying the turbine with - that will tell you the max possible input.

Comment: you're going to need some protection to prevent the generator voltage from exceeding the 42v maximum allowed by the LM22672

Comment: And, going by their images that you link to, don't use shower pipes for the connections - use larger pipe and better connectors to reduce losses...

Comment: This thing needs household water pressure to get any thing useful out. Do you have high pressure like this?  Or, are you attempting to get power from a creek trickle?

Comment: @Mattman944 asked that, but no response...

Comment: You need to give us better cdata. What water source? What flow rate - litres/second or minute or whatever. (If you use gallons specify US or imperial)(vbut, use litres :-) ). | What pressure? and/or what water head?  || Power **at 100% efficiency** ~= metres head x litres/second x 10  Watts.

Comment: @Mattman944 The water source is a lawn irrigation system. I'm not sure what the actual water pressure is, but it should be about the same as a typical household water pressure. The goal is to make a completely underground system that will flip the valves on and off and the turbine will charge a battery for the micro controller.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 The highest voltage I have measured from this thing is about 15V at 20mA. I got this result by attaching it to a power drill and spinning it as fast as I could. This is also after being rectified by the 6 diodes.

Comment: @Parkerowen  In any energy harvesting generator, the challenge is to match impedances and know the required input power to get some efficency.   In your case, the flow = voltage is not enough and torque = water pressure = 60 psi is reduced when flow is allowed.  So you can see the specs of 80V no load and 300mA charge ( near short circuit ) are not met by your flow rate. so your energy captured is only 300 mW instead of 10 W

Comment: The sprinkler heads in your irrigation system may restrict the flow too much. The stated specifications are under ideal conditions (high pressure input, nothing to impede the flow at the output). Continue to run experiments. Based on your power drill test, it is also possible that your unit is defective.